# Would anyone know the code in python that prints ONLY if it's a binary string?

Tags: python, string, binary

The real problem is there:
write a program that takes a **string** as input and prints “Binary Number” if the string contains only 0s or 1s. Otherwise, print “Not a Binary Number”.

Comment: Loop though every letter in the string and check is it 0 or 1?

Comment: @BrainFlooder Yes it is. But the output has to come when the whole input is binary. not if there's any binary digit.

Comment: Then just break the loop if there are?

Comment: yes after when the whole string is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate every character of the input and verify it is a zero or a one. The `all` function can be used for this iteration and check.

Also require that the string has at least one character:

```
def isBinary(string):
    return all(ch in "01" for ch in string) and string != ''
```

Example use:

```
string = input("Enter a binary number: ")
if isBinary(string):
    print("Thank you!")
else:
    print("That is not a binary number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_if_binary(string) :

    p = set(string)
    s = {'0', '1'}

    if s == p or p == {'0'} or p == {'1'}:
        print("Binary Number")
    else :
        print("Not a Binary Number")

 string =  str(input ("Enter the sting : "))
 check_if_binary(string)
```

References: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-check-if-a-given-string-is-binary-string-or-not/

Comment: The code doesn't work for an input string. Here the user will input a string but the error shows that strings cannot be called. Would you solve this somehow?

Comment: @FAOZIAISLAM, are you saying you don't know how to ask for input and pass it to this function?

Comment: I asked the input. But after running the code an error shows and it says the string objects is not callable.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy.

```py
def is_binary(string_to_check:str):
    for x in string_to_check: #loop though all letter
        if x in ('0','1'):
            continue #yep the letter is binary thingy
        else:
            return False #no
    return True #yep the string is binary
```

Next time check google before ask.